# How can I append a sublist only to another list if a term exists in it?

Tags: python

I want to check if an item(here `return`) is in the sublist of `mylist`, if it is then append it to `myOtherlist`, otherwise just append the original `mylist` to `myOtherlist`

`mylist` is under a for loop, that has sub lists that are changing, so it could be the case that `return` term in its sub list is not there.

Here is a case where its there:

Input

```
mylist = [['graph', 'destination'], ['modify', 'destination'], ['modify', 'destination'], ['return', 'modify']]
```

```
    myOtherlist = []
```

My code:

```
    for item in mylist:
        if "return" in item:
            myOtherlist.append(item)
        else:
            myOtherlist.append(mylist)
```

Expected Output:

```
    myOtherlist = [['return', 'modify']]
```

Comment: what is the problem here then?

Comment: Whats in `mylist`?

Comment: What are the inputs?

Comment: remove the `else` statement and you should get the desired output.

Comment: It will be better if you can put some light on mylist?

Comment: Why do you need the `else` part? Removing that, you get the desired output.

Comment: There a huge contradiction in your question. If you want answer as your desired output then why you aksed for this "otherwise just append the original mylist to myOtherlist"

Comment: Sorry guys, edited it now. Does it make sense?

Comment: As @Anonymous says, this still stands unclear. Your explanation of the problem contradicts with your expected output.

Comment: Ok, so I edited it. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `else` statement:

```
mylist = [['graph', 'destination'], ['modify', 'destination'], ['modify', 'destination'], ['return', 'modify']]

myOtherlist = []

for item in mylist:
    if "return" in item:
        myOtherlist.append(item)
myOtherlist = myOtherlist or mylist
```

Or `list` comprehension:

```
myOtherlist = [item for item in mylist if "return" in item] or mylist
```

Comment: Hey, `mylist` is changing and it might be the case that the `return` keyword is not in the sublist, then I'd like`mylist` as it is to get added to my `myOtherlist`

Comment: @AlyssaAlex Edited my answer, please accept it if it works.

Comment: Thanks for both, works! Sorry for being so unclear in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and see if it does what you want. But I can't exactly tell what it is you want this to do.

```py
word_found = False
myList = ["return", "and", "other", "words"]
myOtherList = []
for word in myList:
    if word == "return":
        myOtherList.append(word)
        global word_found = True
if word_found == False:
    myOtherList.append(myList)
```

And for that to have any real use, you'd want it in a functio, like this:

```
def Search(list1, list2, string): #Searches list 1 for a string and if found, adds it to list 2. Otherwise adds all of list 1 to list 2. 
    word_found = False
for word in list1:
    if word == string:
        list2.append(word)
        global word_found = True
if word_found == False:
    list2.append(list1)
```

And, simply out of curiosity, with the example you gave, wouldn't a dictionary have made it wayyyy simpler?

Comment: Can you explain how a dictionary would make it simpler?

Comment: Well, all of their inputs are in groups of 2.  So instead of even having a need to iterate, they could just search the dictionary. As an example, if they wanted to see if return was a key in their dictionary, instead of iterating through their whole list, which can take a pretty long time with larger sets, they could just use dict["return"]

Comment: Why do you make `'return'` as the key of dictionary? Why not value of a key? There is no key-value relation here. Just because input is in groups of 2, does not mean a dictionary is suitable.

Comment: True, but it may serve to add some kind of organization. I mean, the desired functionality is "if the item I want isn't in the list, just take the whole list anyways."  But I do see what you mean. Maybe if they searched for return as a key OR as a value. Then any group of 2 with return it it would be taken.

Comment: Hey, `mylist` is changing and it might be the case that the `return` keyword is not in the sublist, then I'd like `mylist` as it is to get added to my `myOtherlist`

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to make that sound like I thought the case was weird or anything. I could see where this functionality would be needed. I was just saying keeping it in a dictionary might help keep things organized and searchable.